# Stanford NLP: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No annotator named openie

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I'm wondering if anybody can help me.

I'm running the OpenIEDemo from the tutorial, using the stanford-corenlp 3.5.2 maven package.

and I'm receiving the below output:-

> Adding annotator tokenize TokenizerAnnotator: No tokenizer type
>   provided. Defaulting to PTBTokenizer. Adding annotator ssplit Adding
>   annotator pos Reading POS tagger model from
>   edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger
>   ... done [1.5 sec]. Adding annotator lemma Adding annotator depparse
>   Loading depparse model file:
>   edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/english_UD.gz ... PreComputed
>   100000, Elapsed Time: 1.451 (s) Initializing dependency parser done
>   [4.7 sec]. Adding annotator parse Loading parser from serialized file
>   edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz ... done [2.2
>   sec]. Adding annotator natlog Adding annotator openie Exception in
>   thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No annotator named
>   openie
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:83)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:289)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.(StanfordCoreNLP.java:126)
>           at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.(StanfordCoreNLP.java:122)
>           at com.test.OpenIEDemo.OpenIEDemo.main(OpenIEDemo.java:22)

The code is as per the tutorial with the exception that

1. I have changed the package name.
2. I had a previous error that the parse annotator was a dependency for the natlog annotator and so have added the parse annotator into the annotators property.

---

```
package com.test.OpenIEDemo;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.util.RelationTriple;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * A demo illustrating how to call the OpenIE system programmatically.
 */

public class OpenIEDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Create the Stanford CoreNLP pipeline
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,depparse,parse,natlog,openie");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

    // Annotate an example document.
    Annotation doc = new Annotation("Obama was born in Hawaii. He is our president.");
    pipeline.annotate(doc);

    // Loop over sentences in the document
    for (CoreMap sentence : doc.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
      // Get the OpenIE triples for the sentence
      Collection<RelationTriple> triples = sentence.get(NaturalLogicAnnotations.RelationTriplesAnnotation.class);
      // Print the triples
      for (RelationTriple triple : triples) {
        System.out.println(triple.confidence + "\t" +
            triple.subjectLemmaGloss() + "\t" +
            triple.relationLemmaGloss() + "\t" +
            triple.objectLemmaGloss());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should try this with Stanford CoreNLP 3.6.0 not 3.5.2

Comment: thanks this works with 3.6.0